# Is there a replacement for the in 6.3 deprecated @Where and @Loader

Tags: hibernate, deprecation-warning

Since hibernate 6.3 org.hibernate.annotations.Where and Loader are deprecated.

We are using these annotations together with @NamedQuery and @SQLDelete to implement soft deletion.

What is de non-deprecated way of implementing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.html) you can replace `@Where` annotation to `@SQLRestriction`:

From:

```
 @Entity
 @Where(clause = "status <> 'DELETED'")
 class Document {
     ...
     @Enumerated(STRING)
     Status status;
     ...
 }
```

To:

```
 @Entity
 @SQLRestriction("status <> 'DELETED'")
 class Document {
     ...
     @Enumerated(STRING)
     Status status;
     ...
 }
```

Also according to [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Loader.html) you also can replace `@Loader` to `@SQLSelect` or `@HQLSelect`

About `@HQLSelect` and `@SQLSelect`

> These annotation is just an abbreviation for Loader together with
> NamedQuery.

More information about **HOW TO DO IT**  I think you should check attached references to documentation about it.

Comment: I should have found that documentation myself... Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: you are welcome, don`t forget to accept this answer as right one.

Comment: I think this should be accepted as the right answer